# Rendering component based on state/prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been learning React and I was wondering how would I be able to render classes/components based on the state?

I was thinking perhaps putting something like:

```
var currentState = this.state.title;
< currentState />
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I can do it using if statements or case/switch but that doesn't seem to be particularly flexible.

Here is what I'm working with currently:

```
var Proj1 = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <h1>Number one</h1>
        )   
    }
});

var Proj2 = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <h1>Number two</h1>
        )   
    }
});

var ContentContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            title: 'Proj1'
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            ///// Proj1?
        )
    }
});

React.render(
    <ContentContainer/>, document.getElementById('container')
 );
```

Essentially I'd like to render the appropriate class based on the current name of the state. For example if the state.title = Proj1, i'd like to render Proj1, alternatively if the state.title = Proj2, i'd like to render Proj2.

Please and thanks

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a comment on top of Tyler McGinnis but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do that :).
I think the edited answer 'worked' but still we need a map between title and the class. 
A way to do is to store these React Classes to an accessible object, like

```
Components = {};
Components.Proj1 = React.createClass({...}};
Components.Proj2 = React.createClass({...}};
...
ContentContainer = React.createClass({
    return (
        var Proj = Components[this.state.title];
        <Proj/>
});
```

I think that's still a bit hack-ish, and I don't have a better answer.

I think most of the time, React component states are used to control certain html/css properties, your use case is more like using object factory to create/get different type of objects, in which using if statement doesn't seem to bad.

Comment: hm yeah i was thinking of something like that, I guess `this.state.title` or if I were to send that as a prop to a child element `this.props.currentstate`, the `this.state.title` doesn't like export when it's in a variable. for example, if i write `var Proj10 = Proj1; return <Proj10/>` it does render Proj1 but if I write `var Proj = this.state.title; return <Proj/>` it doesn't render Proj1

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this. All basically are just if statements though. I'd probably go with something like this and use a ternary operator, that's usually the most common practice.

```
var ContentContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            title: 'Proj1'
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return this.state.title === 'Proj1' ? <Proj1 /> : </Proj2>;
    }
});
```

edit: I think you're wanting to know how to set components to variables. In this example,

```
var currentState = this.state.title;
< currentState />
```

if we assume this.state.title was a component (which it's not), then you would just need to capitalize currentState.

For example.

```
getInitialState(){
  return {
    proj1: Proj1 //Proj1 is a React Component.
  }
}
render(){
  var Proj1 = this.state.proj1; //you just need to capitalize the variable name.
  return <Proj1 />
}
```

Comment: Yeaahh, I know it's possible to do it with if statements, but I mean lets say for example i had up to Proj20, but thanks for the response!

Comment: @slickrick Edited my answer. I think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks, hm that didnt seem to work either, I guess I'll just stick to if statements then