# render component based on state in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, components

I am using [react-native-side-menu](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu) for the menu in the app. Since this module using state to control the clicked menu, I would like to used it to render the component as well.

I am referred to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193854/rendering-component-based-on-state-prop-in-react) But it is not working, I got

> Expected a component class, got [object Object].

This is what I did:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Menu from './menu';

import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu';
import First from './first';
import Second from './second';

module.exports = class Main extends Component {
    state = {
    isOpen: false,
    selectedItem: 'First',
  };

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
    });
  }

  updateMenuState(isOpen) {
    this.setState({ isOpen, });
  }

  onMenuItemSelected = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false,
      selectedItem: item,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;

    return (
      <SideMenu
        menu={menu}
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        onChange={(isOpen) => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}
        >
        <this.state.selectedItem />
        <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.toggle()}>
          <Image
            source={require('./assets/menu.png')} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
        </Button>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
}
....
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for @NaderDabit suggest. Yes indeed, I should use

```
selectedItem: <First />,
```

instead.

Comment: Is it because 'First' is set as a string vs a component? `selectedItem: 'First'`

Comment: @NaderDabit I don't get it.

Comment: @NaderDabit, I got it. I will give it a test, and get back with the result.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific. I mean try `selectedIem: First` vs `selectedItem: 'First'`